# How to set value of current logged-in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm creating an active admin form where I want to set the value of "admin_user_id" to be the current user logging in and want to hide this as we don't need to show while filling the form. here is my form for active admin:

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :admin_user_id, input_html: { value: current_admin_user }
      f.input :title
      f.input :description
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

Comment: I don't actually see a question or an error here can you please advise what about this is not working?

Comment: I want the value of admin_usser_id to be set automatically as current_admin_user without showing in the form. Active admin should detect which admin has generated this without asking.

Comment: @Fuaad, you can try `<%= f.hidden_field :admin_user_id, value: current_admin_user.id %>` or you can get current admin user in the controller instead of showing it in the form.

Comment: @remy727 actually, it's ruby file. so, how can we use embedded ruby syntax here? Can you please ellaborate how to set current_admin_user in controller?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by replacing "current_admin_user" with "current_admin_user.id".

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :admin_user_id, input_html: { value: current_admin_user.id }
      f.input :title
      f.input :description
    end
    f.actions
  end
```